# Any script to plot multi axis FDR / flight-test data (such as the ones used in air crash investigation)?

Tags: flight-controls, accidents, accident-investigation

I am looking for a script or tool to create flight test and/or FDR plots with several vertical axis, such as the ones used in aircraft accident investigations.

Does anyone have any hint on a MATLAB or Python script that does it? I have the data and I know how to code, just didn't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Example:
[image]
[Source](http://www.bst-tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/2011/a11h0002/Images/a11h0002-figure-18.png)

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. I'll wait for the opinion of the other members, but I am afraid your question might not be on topic here. You are not properly asking an aviation question here, but only how to make a specific plot in Matlab/Python/whatever

Comment: Hi Federico! I thought that someone that works in the aircraft industry (just like me) would have already created a script for such objective. I am afraid a Python or MATLAB programmer/enthusiast would hardly have access for flight data to play with.

Comment: I see your point, and that's why I did not immediately hammer your post down. The problem is that from a quality point of view, this question is little more than "please give me the code/solution" that is a bit frowned upon around stackechange. Should the others agree with you, no problem. If instead they should vote to close this question, stick around, gain a bit of reputation, and pass by chat!

Comment: Do you have *raw* data taken directly from say a QAR or test telemetry/recording device, or *processed* data that's already converted to engineering units and standard sign conventions? (an example of the latter is "climbing right turns are positive", which is what the NTSB uses for all their FDR plotting)

Comment: In fact I have both raw and engineering units data.

Comment: The problem with predefined scripts is that most of the time, the variable designation doesn’t match, anyway, so it’s almost as quick whipping it up from scratch... at least for the most common parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think these plots are generated from Matlab or Python, but from special-purpose software. This was discussed in chat a couple of months ago, and one example is [Insight Analysis](http://www.flightscape.com/product_service/insight-analysis/), which offers a GUI interface to put together the kind of chart you're looking for. It's definitely not the only such tool, though.